# How to convert all internal usage of int to BigInteger in a class

Tags: java

How do I change the constructors/code so they match with the "BigInteger" function? I don't know how to change them and but at the same time not change the interface, nor the signature of any public constructor or public method.

```
public class RatNum {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;
  
// Constructors
public RatNum(){
    this.numerator = 0;
    this.denominator = 1;
}
public RatNum(int a){
    this.numerator = a;
    this.denominator = 1;
}
private RatNum gcd(BigInteger a, BigInteger b){

}
```

Comment: Please copy all the relevant code, as text, into your question. Including everything contained in the image.

Comment: Why not `BigInteger.valueOf(n)`?

Answer (score 1):

Add another constructor in code with `BigInteger` type:

```
public RatNum(BigInteger n, BigInteger d) {
    this.numerator = n;
    this.denominator = d;
}
```

Update existing contructors:

```
public RatNum() {
    this.numerator = BigInteger.ZERO;
    this.denominator = BigInteger.ONE;
}

public RatNum(int a) {
    this.numerator = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
    this.denominator = BigInteger.ONE;
}
```

And change `getNumerator` and `getDenominator` methods (or add `getNumeratorBigInt` and `getDenominatorBigInt`):

```
public BigInteger getNumerator() {
    return this.numerator;
}

public BigInteger getDenominator() {
    return this.denominator ;
}
```

Comment: Good Answer. I suggest further improving by showing the revamped class in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use predefined `static` constants available in the `BigInteger` class or use the method `BigDecimal.value(long)`:

```
public RatNum() {
    this.numerator = BigInteger.ZERO;
    this.denominator = BigInteger.ONE;
}

public RatNum(int a) {
    this.numerator = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
    this.denominator = BigInteger.ONE;
}
```

For sake of a good design, you want to use one proper primary constructor with a bunch of secondary ones:

```
// primary
public RatNum(int a) {
    this.numerator = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
    this.denominator = BigInteger.ONE;
}

// secondary constructors refer to the primary one
public RatNum() {
    this(0);
}
```